# radiobuttons c# strange behaviour after submitting

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an strange behaviour with 2 radiobuttons.

```
<asp:RadioButton  GroupName="grp_anexo" id="rdioAnexoSi"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdioAnexoSi_CheckedChanged" />SI

<asp:RadioButton   GroupName="grp_anexo" id="rdioAnexoNo"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdioAnexoNo_CheckedChanged" />NO
```

i CHECKED "rdioAnexoSi",

When click a button(submit), automatically select "rdioAnexoNo".

why  radiobutton  is changing to "rdioAnexoNo" when i selected myself "rdioAnexoSi" after submitting?

```
 $('#formIngreso').attr('action', "proceso.aspx").submit();


 protected void rdioAnexoNo_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        if (chk != null)
        {
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                ddlAnexo.Items.Clear();
                ddlAnexoN.Items.Clear();
                div_anexo.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                div_anexo.Visible = true;
            }

        }
    }


 protected void rdioCelularSi_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        if (chk != null)
        {
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                ddlCelular.Items.Clear();
                sap sapserver = new sap();
                sapserver.arr_parametros = sapserver.LecturaArchivo(300);
                sapserver.rfc_config_conex = sapserver.SapParametros(sapserver.arr_parametros);
                if (sapserver.probarConexionSap(sapserver.rfc_config_conex) == true)
                {
                    RfcDestination RfcDestino = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(sapserver.rfc_config_conex);
                    sapserver.mostrarpep_cecos(RfcDestino, ddlCelular, ddlArea.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim());

                }
                else
                {

                }

                div_celular.Visible = true;
            }
        }




    }
```

Comment: Might have to do with `Checked='true'` fpr rdioAnexoNo ?

Comment: sorry i edited the code..

Comment: post this "rdioAnexoNo_CheckedChanged" event code

Comment: What are you doing in button(submit) click event? are you sure you are not checking the different radiobutton?

Comment: Why are your `CheckedChanged` event handlers looking for a `CheckBox` sender instead of a `RadioButton` sender? Might that be part of your problem? I would also possibly consider looking at the `RadioButtonList` control instead. Just a thought.

Comment: What is in your `Page_Load` and `submit` action serverside?

Answer (score 0):

If you have AutoPostBack set to true why do you need this line

```
 $('#formIngreso').attr('action', "proceso.aspx").submit();
```

and when do you call it?